# python - remove namespace and print only the required string

Tags: python

I have the code below which stores the values in a list. the output prints all the values in the list but with namespace. My question is,

1. how to print without namespace?
2. how to print only the value I need?

For example, from the output below I only need to print name2,

```
['Channel1\nName2\n4Time']
```

Below is my code,

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import subprocess, sys
    firstarg=sys.argv[1]
    result = []
    service_provider = subprocess.Popen (['ffprobe', '-loglevel', 'fatal', '-select_streams', 'p:program_id=p:1', '-show_entries', 'program_tags=service_name', '-of', 'csv=%s' % ("p=0"), '-i', sys.argv[1]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    out = service_provider.communicate() [0]
    result = list()
    result.append(out)
    print result
```

Comment: Is the patter provided same over all the lists?

Comment: @MohitMotwani yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code and solve your problem by substituting:

```
result = list()
result.append(out)
```

with:

```
result = out.split('\n')
```

Comment: Also, `result = []` at the beginning is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
[e.split('\n')[1] for e in ['Channel1\nName2\n4Time']]

Out[256]: ['Name2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by the `"\n"` character and get the string that you need

```
x = ['Channel1\nName2\n4Time']
x[0].split("\n")[1]
```

output

```
'Name2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() and split the string on '\n'

```
x = ['Channel1\nName2\n4Time', 'Channel1\nName2\n4Time']
[i.split('\n') for i in x]

Output: [['Channel1', 'Name2', '4Time'], ['Channel1', 'Name2', '4Time']]
```

Then use the lists to select any element you would like using indexing.